# Could not open android app with release with Flutter beta 1.25.0-8.1.pre

Tags: flutter

I've recently updated Flutter to 1.25.0-8.1.pre in beta. I could run `debug` apk and build `release`. But, the `release-apk` doesn't work and it stuck on default splash screen. Where the problem lies in. Is there any such bug from Flutter?

`flutter doctor:`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.1.pre, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgrade the flutter version to 1.24.0-10.2.pre which released on 11/19/2020 and retried building release apk. And it worked fine. Actually the problem lies with Flutter new update on beta. The corresponding issue : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72705

Comment: Did you try flutter clean before flutter build ?

Comment: yes, but, the release apk was not running. and also I tried from different computers

Comment: Did you run debug builds?

Comment: yes, pls try a run with release and make it sure.